# Shopping cart price rule condition

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

I have created a shopping cart price rule for discount.
I want to give a free product for some purchase to customers, so I have created a rule and set action for 100% discount on this product.
I have defined product sku under action tab as-

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
    SKU  is  gwb-test3

it is working when I add a single quantity, but when we add more than 1 quantity then discount is appear for all quantity, but I want to give discount only one quanity for this product.
Please suggest some rule conditions or actions for this.

Comment: @Perry I have put the rule condition on product sku. i not understand which use of id here ??

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the product id I didn't read the question right. But here is a link to your solution:

http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/shopping-cart-price-rules

Search for: Shopping Cart Price Rule Actions

There is your answer :)